# Combine two raster layers, setting NA values in non-mask layer to 0 where mask layer is not NA

Tags: r, raster

I have two raster layers that I wish to combine into one. Let's call them `mask` (with values `1` and `NA`), and `vrs`.

```
library(raster)
mask <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
mask[] <- c(rep(0, 50), rep(1, 50))
mask[mask < 0.5] <- NA
vrs <-raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
vrs[] <- rpois(100, 2)
vrs[vrs >= 4] <- NA
```

I wish to combine two big layers, but for the sake of understanding these small examples are ok. What I wish to do is to set the pixel values of my output layer to zero for those pixels where `mask` layer is `1` and `vrs` layer is `NA`. All other pixels should remain with the values of original `vrs`.

This is my only thought as to how:

```
zero.for.NA <- function(x, y, filename){
  out <- raster(y)
  if(canProcessInMemory(out, n = 4)) { #wild guess..
    val <- getValues(y) #values
    NA.pos <- which(is.na(val)) #positiones for all NA-values in values-layer
    NA.t.noll.pos<-which(x[NA.pos]==1) #Positions where mask is 1 within the 
                                       #vector of positions of NA values in vrs
    val[NA.pos[NA.t.noll.pos]] <- 0 #set values layer to 0 where condition met
    out <- setValues(out, val)
    return(out)
  } else { #for large rasters the same thing by chunks
    bs <- blockSize(out)
    out <- writeStart(out, filename, overwrite=TRUE)
    for (i in 1:bs$n) {
      v <- getValues(y, row=bs$row[i], nrows=bs$nrows[i])
      xv <- getValues(x, row=bs$row[i], nrows=bs$nrows[i])
      NA.pos <- which(is.na(v))
      NA.t.noll.pos <- which(xv[NA.pos]==1)
      v[NA.pos[NA.t.noll.pos]] <- 0
      out <- writeValues(out, v, bs$row[i])
    }
    out <- writeStop(out)
    return(out)
  }
}
```

This function did work on the small example and seems to work on the bigger ones. Is there a faster/better way of doing this? Some way that is better for larger files? I will have to use this on many sets of layers and I would appreciate any help in making the process safer and or quicker!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `cover()`:

```
r <- cover(vrs, mask-1)
plot(r)
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent! Thank you @Josh O'Brien! It turns out this is faster on my data and my computer, so it seems there are at least three ways and the one in this answer is the fastest version. Continued from comment to previous post by @jbaums: `system.time(vrs_big_again2<-cover(vrs_big,mask_big-1,filename="~/savetest2"))`gave the response: user  system elapsed 
  90.17    7.19  129.00 
and `identical(values(ny_ips90_1),values(ny_ips90_1_igen2))`
[1] TRUE

Comment: @MariaCSa -- Impressive that your hand-written function was that close, performance-wise, to the simple call above! Nicely done. Also, thanks for providing such a nicely reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `overlay`, as well:

```
r <- overlay(mask, vrs, fun=function(x, y) ifelse(x==1 & is.na(y), 0, y))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @jbaums! This gives the same result as my function but curiously on my big rasters with `system.time()` I clocked the two versions:`system.time(vrs_big <- zero.for.NA(mask_big,vrs_big,filename="~/vrs_big"))`
   user  system elapsed 
  90.21   10.53  105.68 
`system.time(vrs_big_igen<-overlay(mask_big,vrs_big,fun=function(x,y)ifelse(x==1 & is.na(y), 0 , y ),filename="~/savetest"))`
   user  system elapsed 
 169.59   24.46  197.73 
`identical(values(vrs_big),values(vrs_big_igen))`
[1] TRUE